# building correct algorithm to append each bit in a list

Tags: python, list, append

I am trying to write a program in Python that will take out each bit from a list and add it to a variable. 
Example:

```
x = list(range(0, 11))
y = raw_input("Enter your number: ")
```

So I want `y` to add itself to each bit from `0`-`11`.

Why? Let's say I want the a sum of 10 so I wrote in `y` the number `5`, so now I want it to find the correct number in the list that will equal to a sum of 10.

Comment: What do you mean by "each bit"?

Comment: Actually, why can't you just do `10 - int(y)`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to build the list at all (in fact, in Python 2.x, `range` gives you a list already). I think what you want is something like:

```
target = 10 # set target
y = raw_input("Enter your number: ") # get string input, e.g. '5'
y = int(y) # convert to an actual integer number, e.g. 5
for x in range(1, target+1): # loop through numbers
    if x + y == target: # test whether we reached the target
        print("Need to add {0} to {1} to get {2}.".format(x, y, target)) # win!
        break # stop looping
```

Although bear in mind that you're simply working out `x` such that:

```
x == target - y
```

which you can calculate directly.

---

Note that in programming "bit" [has a specific meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit); you should refer to the things in lists as "items", "values" or "objects".

Comment: @user2634624 if you found it useful consider up voting or accepting - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Also, http://overcompensating.com/oc/index.php?comic=272